# How to discriminate JSON code formatting by removing empty lines using Eslint + Prettier

Tags: javascript, json, eslint, prettier, blank-line

**BACKGROUND**

When creating test files there is normally a lot of copy and paste of JSON objects (even if you use your own factories). I find that if you modify schema sometimes it easier to find and replace on the key + pair. The issue is that the find and replace in IDE's (unless you can customize it ... VSCode, Intellij, etc.?) will not do a auto post-save cleanup if what you replaced originally produces a empty line in the JSON object.

---

**ASK**

**Is there a way to configure `eslint` and/or `prettier` that on auto save it will condense your JSON objects by removing empty lines?**

(If not, does anybody have a **regex** that can **differentiate between code blocks / closures vs. JSON objects** and remove any blank lines?)

---

**EXAMPLE: JSON Objects in JavaScript Files**

Before Formatting

```
const blah = {
   EffectiveDate: '2019-01-01',
   DiscontinueDate: '2019-12-12',

   MarkDownCode: 'W'
}
```

After Formatting

```
const blah = {
   EffectiveDate: '2019-01-01',
   DiscontinueDate: '2019-12-12',
   MarkDownCode: 'W'
}
```

Comment: VSCode allows you to search and replace with RegEx. Open the replace dialog(ctrl+h) and hit the regex icon or press alt+r. `^\n` will grab every empty new line. You can replace it with an empty string and your lines will collapse. As far as differentiating, there wouldn't be any efficient way of doing this since JSON and object literals aren't verifiably different through code checks afaik, so barring separate files or some sort of intentional syntax distinction, unfortunately I think you're out of luck. Aside: the code you have isn't valid JSON so this is likely impossible.

Comment: @Aaron Are you talking about JavaScript objects in .js files, or actual JSON code in .json files? The code you posted isn't JSON, it's JavaScript

Comment: Hey @Patrick Hund, was referring to JavaScript files. Ill update the  example to include more context. Thank you!

Comment: @zfrisch it should be valid now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can only set prettier to condense multiple sequential empty lines into one empty line.

What you **can** do, though, is use any text editor with a Find&Replace functionality that accepts a Regex expression and then replacing:

`^\n`

for an empty string:

`''`

Usually the Find&Replace can be opened using `Ctrl+H`.

Additionally, I would add that if you were so inclined to achieve automation of this task you could look into extensions for your code editor that allows some type of "Run on Save" functionality and then adding a little script to erase those new lines.